# Split up List<Node> nodes into List<List<nodes>> listofnodes based on parameters associated with nodes

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<Node> nodes`. And `class Node` can be defined as follows:

```
 public class Node
{
    public int Density { get; set; }
    public List<Edge> adjnodes { get; set; }


    public Node()
    {
        adjnodes = new List<Edge>();

    }

    public static int GetDensity(Node n)
    {
        return n.Density;
    }

}
```

Now, each node in nodes have a density value associated with it which is calculated using following random function:

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();  

public static int generateRandom(int min, int max)
        {
            int random = rnd.Next(min, max);
            return random;
        }
```

And I use `generateRandom()` as follows in the `static void main` :

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int densityRandom = YelloWPages.generateRandom(1, 10);
            nodes[i].Density = densityRandom;
            Console.WriteLine("Node is " + nodes[i] + "and density " + nodes[i].Density + "Interest.Array[0] " + nodes[i].P1.InterestArray[0]);
        }
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Suppose there is a `List<List<Nodes>> listofnodes`. Each List in listofnodes (For example say listofnodes[0] -> which is a first element and a list). has a maximum capacity as defined by user. In our example let it be 10.

I want a forloop to check density of each node in nodes. If it is greater than 5, it should go in one of the lists of `listofnodes`. Now, suppose there are 100 nodes and 55 of them have density greater than 5. First 10 should go in some listofnodes[i] list while next 10 in listofnodes[i+1]... till all 55 are in one of the lists of listofnodes. But only condition is size of `listofnodes[i]` or `listofnodes[i+1]` or whichever should not be more than 10. This is something I tried but it clearly does not work out:

```
public static void DivideandInsert(List<Node> list)
    {
        List<List<Node>> smallList = new List<List<Node>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < smallList.Count; k++)
            {
                if (list[i].Density > 5 && smallList[k].Count != 10)
                {
                    smallList[k].Add(list[i]);
                }
                else smallList[k + 1].Add(list[i]);

            }
        }
    }
```

If at all it would have worked. But its giving me size of smallList as 0 after the operation is performed.

1. If at all this logic is correct, where I am going wrong?

Help to resolve this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I believe the error may lie in your object creation, as the loops should never enter to have argumentoutofbounds

Comment: @user2338488 I have updated question. I am not getting error now but size of smallList remains 0 even after addition operation!

Comment: What Steve has pointed out below is throwing NullReferenceException however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this how you should do it instead

```
public static void DivideandInsert(List<Node> list)
   {
        List<List<Node>> smallList = new List<List<Node>>();
         //an extra list
        List<Node> filtered_list = new List<Node>(); 

     //This part will get you all the 55 nodes with density > 5
     foreach(Node n in list) 
     {
       if(n.Density > 5)
       {
           filtered_list.Add(n);
       }
    } 
  int count  = filtered_list.Count;
  int sublist_count  = (count % 10 == 0) ? count / 10 : count / 10 + 1;

       for(int i=0;i<sublist_count;i++)
        {
                List<Node> sublist = new List<Node>();

                for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                {
                    sublist.Add(filtered_list[k]);
                }
            smallList.Add(sublist);
        }   
  }
```

Comment: Now it is throwing ArgumentOutofBoundsException at else part.

Comment: How does this work? I am not able to figure out. Can you please exaplin?

Comment: @DotNetNewBie, give a minute .. I am editing. The way you are doing is logically incorrect

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer but I am getting ArgumentOutOfException at line (smallList[j].Count < 10)

Comment: @DotNetNewBie, replace `smallList[j].Count < 10` with `i < 10`. see edit again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51718/discussion-between-dotnetnewbie-and-rahul)

Comment: I believe it has to do something with smallList[j] part.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<Node>> smallList = 
    nodes.Where(n => n.Density > 5)
         .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
         .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 10)
         .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
         .ToList();
```

Get the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419063/1251423).

Answer (score 0):

Your smallList is empty when you try to access it.

Comment: Ya. I guessed it. And I guess that is the reason why that error. But the how that can be resolved?

Comment: Actually I don't see how the inner loop is ever entered since smallList.Count is zero.  What line is the exception thrown on?

Comment: I dont know why but exception is not thrown now. however, nothing is getting added in smallList. I checked smallList.count and its turning out to be 0.